# Kubernetes HPA based on available healthy pods

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have the HPA scale based on the number of available running pods?

I have set up a readiness probe that cuts out a pod based it's internal state (idle, working, busy).  When a pod is 'busy', it no longer receives new requests.  But the cpu, and memory demands are low.

I don't want to scale based on cpu, mem, or other metrics.

Seeing as the readiness probe removes it from active service, can I scale based on the average number of active (not busy) pods?  When that number drops below a certain point more pods are scaled.

TIA for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [custom metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics), a number of `busy-pods` for HPA.
That is, the application should emit a metric value when it is busy. And use that metric to create HorizontalPodAutoscaler.

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: custom-metric-sd
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: custom-metric-sd
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 20
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: busy-pods
      targetAverageValue: 4
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling) is another reference for HPA with custom metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.